# Propagating errors for percentage reduction

Tags: lab-techniques

Need a bit of help for this particular problem.

I have three averages collected from three genotypes (A, B, and C) and their associated SD (a, b, and c). A is my control.

I have been asked to represent the data as a percentage reduction as compared to A. How do I propagate my error?

Calculation:

- % Reduction for A = (1-A/A)100%
- % Reduction for B = (1-B/A)100%
- % Reduction for C = (1-C/A)*100%

Thanks a ton!